# How to use pytest command for code optimization

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, tdd, pytest

So, I am new in TDD and I recently had technical interview about task assignment that I did earlier. In interview, interviewer run some pytest command that pointed out these two lines in my code that suppose to be optimized:

`final_schedule[opening_day].append(f'{opening_schedule} - {closing_schedule}')`
`final_schedule[self.days[6]].append(f'{opening_schedule} - {closing_schedule}')`

Now i am trying to find that pytest command that I can run in order to find what to be optimized my code in future but I am unable to find it. I am not sure if it was just a pytest command that he run. I am wondering if someone could help me in finding that command? Thanks!

Comment: Why not asking the person that you had the interview with about this?

Comment: I think it's the best way, and I also think you will get points for asking them this. If you will try to get hired by the same person in the future he might remember you just by the fast that you  came back and asked questions about your interview :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is [pytest-benchmark](https://github.com/ionelmc/pytest-benchmark). This helps us know which tests take the most amount of time.
From the README
[image: output of pytest with benchmark]